# В чем ошибка программы сортировки?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Есть программа визуализации сортировки слиянием. 
До этого реализовывал примерно также пузырьком, расческой и выбором, но только тут началась какая-то чертовщина. Сама функция работает, но не могу понять в чем дело

Это алгоритм

```js
function mergeSort(arr, key) {
 var result;

 if (arr.length <= 1) {
  return arr
 }

 const middle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
    const left = arr.slice(0, middle);
    const right = arr.slice(middle);

 return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right), key);
}

function merge(left, right, key) {
 var result = [],
  i = j = 0;
 if (!left) {
  left = []
 }
 if (!right) {
  right = []
 }
 while (i < left.length && j < right.length) {
  result.push(
   (left[i][key] < right[j][key]) ?
    left[i++] : right[j++]
  );
 }
 return [
  ...result,
  ...left.slice(i),
  ...right.slice(j)
 ];
}
```

А это функция отрисовки

```js
function draw() {
 cleanWindow(true);
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var x = elements[i].x,
   y = elements[i].y,
   height = elements[i].height,
   h = elements[i].h,
   s = elements[i].s,
   l = elements[i].l;
  c.beginPath();
  c.rect(i, y,
      1, -height);
  c.fillStyle = `hsl(${h}, ${s}%, ${l}%`;
  c.fill();
  c.closePath();
 }
 
 elements = mergeSort(elements, 'height');
}
```

Алгоритм возвращает отсортированный массив в этот же массив
Keys нужна, так как в этой же программе сортирую не только по высоте, но и по цвету.
В elements добавляется объект с координатами, но для удобства этого алгоритма, решил за х брать отсортированное положение индекса.

Вот весь код

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Merge Sort</title>
 <style>
  * {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
  }

  canvas {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
 <script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
 c = canvas.getContext('2d'),
 x = 0, y = 0,
 elements = [],
 bgColor = '#000';
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var k = 0;

var ex = ey = 0;
document.onclick = function(e) { // выводит текущие координаты при клике
      ex = e.clientX;
      ey = e.clientY;
    };


cleanWindow(true);
for (var i = 0; i <= canvas.width; i++) {
 height = randInt(0, canvas.height);
 elements.push({
  x: i,
  y: canvas.height,
  height: height,
  // h: randRange(0, 360),
  h: 0,
  s: 100,
  l: 50
 })
 h = elements[i].h;
 s = elements[i].s;
 l = elements[i].l;
 c.beginPath();
 c.rect(x, canvas.height,
   1, -height);
 c.fillStyle = `hsl(${h}, ${s}%, ${l}%`;
 c.fill();
 c.closePath();
}

setInterval(draw, 1);

function draw() {
 cleanWindow(true);
 if (document.onclick && ex && ey) {
  elements[ex].height = canvas.height-ey;
 }
 ex = ey = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var x = elements[i].x,
   y = elements[i].y,
   height = elements[i].height,
   h = elements[i].h,
   s = elements[i].s,
   l = elements[i].l;
  c.beginPath();
  c.rect(i, y,
      1, -height);
  c.fillStyle = `hsl(${h}, ${s}%, ${l}%`;
  c.fill();
  c.closePath();
 }
 
 elements = mergeSort(elements, 'height');

}

function mergeSort(arr, key) {
 var result;

 if (arr.length <= 1) {
  return arr
 }

 const middle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
    const left = arr.slice(0, middle);
    const right = arr.slice(middle);

 return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right), key);
}

function merge(left, right, key) {
 var result = [],
  i = j = 0;
 if (!left) {
  left = []
 }
 if (!right) {
  right = []
 }
 while (i < left.length && j < right.length) {
  result.push(
   (left[i][key] < right[j][key]) ?
    left[i++] : right[j++]
  );
 }
 return [
  ...result,
  ...left.slice(i),
  ...right.slice(j)
 ];
}


function cleanWindow(visible) {
 if (visible) {
  c.beginPath();
  c.rect(0, 0,
      canvas.width, canvas.height);
  c.fillStyle = bgColor;
  c.fill();
  c.closePath();
 }
}

function randInt(min, max, except) {
 if (except !== undefined) {
  var result = Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
  if (result !== except) {
   return result;
  }
  return randInt(min, max, except);
 }
 return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min));
}

function randRange(min, max, step) {
 if (step !== undefined) {
  var result = Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min));
  if (result % step !== 0) {
   return randRange(min, max, step);
  } else {
   return result
  }
 }
 return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min));
}
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: опишите или приложите скрин ошибки, с телефона не работает Ваш пример кода

Comment: Это не полный код, сейчас выложу весь

Comment: Иногда список генерируется так, что это становится похожим на слияние, но дальше не уходит

Comment: Key я убрал для упрощения, и у меня работает: js.do/code/295243 и Ваш код со слайсами, кстати, тоже работает. Ответ удаляю, т.к. получается, что ничего нового он не несёт.

Comment: Я, видимо, забыл дописать, что сам алгоритм у меня работает и сортирует числа. Но палки по высоте не сортируются, хотя в таких же условиях с другими алгоритмами все работало